# Just Audio Flutter Plugin - How to catch song completion event

Tags: flutter, events, plugins, just-audio

I am using just_audio plugin for flutter by Ryan Heise. I am able to get events of buffering, ready, loading, completed, etc.

Is there a way to get an event of a song completing in a playlist? I can't seem to find one in the documentation. We need to update the UI to show the next song is playing.

Thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a `StreamBuilder` which listens to `just_audio`'s `currentIndexStream`. This way, there will always be up-to-date info: If  the state updates, your build triggers and the widget showing the data is rebuilt.

In the setup on pub, different available streams for you to listen to are listed, among which is the `currentIndexStream`, which I assume solves your problem by streaming the current value (which, in conjunction with your list of songs should be able to get you the info you need)

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: player.currentIndexStream,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    int currentIndex = snapshot.data ?? 0;
    print(currentIndex.toString());
    return MySongInfoWidget(song: mySongList[currentIndex]);
  }
);
```

The code above should at least give you an idea of how to approach this problem, take a look at [the StreamBuilder docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) for more info.

A bit more complete example (to show how a streambuilder could be used inside build):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(...),
    body: Column(children: [
      myStaticWidget(...),
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: player.currentIndexStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          int currentIndex = snapshot.data ?? 0;
          return Column(children: [
            Text('Current song #$currentIndex'),
            Text('Song name: ${mySongs[currentIndex].name}');
          ]);
        }
      ),
    ]),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply fravolt. I am able to get the index of the song correctly now. The changing song in the playlist is properly triggering the index change. I have another problem now. I was using the stream: _audioPlayer.playerStateStream, to get the buffering, ready state and then returning the widgets. Now all I need to do is change the label on the list to the new song label. When I setState inside the other stream: player.currentIndexStream, it of course goes into a loop of state changes. Any suggestion on how to update the label in this stream?

Comment: I wouldn't even use the state for the index: Using a streambuilder and building from there should immediately build the widget, if you put the streambuilder inside your build function.

It's possible to wrap one streambuilder in another one if you want your built widget to depend on 2 streams. (Alternatively, use something like the [multiple stream builder package](https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_stream_builder) to make the code a bit cleaner).

Comment: I just added another example, showing how you could use streambuilder inside your build function immediately. You should keep in mind the stream could return some unexpected things at first, so it's always good to check whether `snapshot.hasData` and what the `snapshot.connectionStatus` is before returning the actual info

Comment: Thank you fravolt. Will try some variations to see how this works.